# How To: Joining three lists using Linq to objects

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Problem is with the addresses not being outputted

```
          using System;
          using System.Collections.Generic;
          using System.Linq;
          using System.Text;

          namespace LinqToObjects
          {
            class Program
          {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customers = Customer.GetAllCustomers();
        var addresses = Address.GetAllAddresses();
        var addressRelations = AddressRelation.GetAllAddressRelations();

        var results = customers
                    .Join(addressRelations,
                    c => c.CustomerID,
                    ar => ar.CustomerID,
                    (c, ar) => new
                    {
                        CustomerName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                        CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                        AddressRelID = ar.AddressID
                    });
        var resultsJoined = results
                       .GroupJoin(addresses,
                        ar => ar.AddressRelID,
                        a => a.AddressID,
                        (ar, a) => new
                        {
                            CustomerName = ar.CustomerName,
                            AddressLine = addresses.Select(b => b.StreetAddress).FirstOrDefault()
                        });
        foreach(var item in resultsJoined)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.CustomerName);
            Console.WriteLine(item.AddressLine);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");

        }
    }
}

public class AddressRelation
{
    public int AddressRelationID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public AddressRelation(int id, int customerId, int addressId)
    {
        AddressRelationID = id; CustomerID = customerId; AddressID = addressId;
    }
    public static List<AddressRelation> GetAllAddressRelations()
    {
        var AllAddressRelations = new List<AddressRelation>();//simulate data returned from db
        var addressRelation1 = new AddressRelation(1, 1, 1);
        var addressRelation2 = new AddressRelation(2, 3, 3);
        var addressRelation3 = new AddressRelation(3, 2, 2);
        AllAddressRelations.Add(addressRelation1);
        AllAddressRelations.Add(addressRelation2);
        AllAddressRelations.Add(addressRelation3);

        return AllAddressRelations;
    }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public Address(int id, string streetAddress)
    {
        AddressID = id; StreetAddress = streetAddress;
    }
    public static List<Address> GetAllAddresses()
    {
        var AllAddresses = new List<Address>();
        Address customer1Address = new Address(1, "Elm St");
        Address customer2Address = new Address(2, "Willow Way");
        Address customer3Address = new Address(3, "Linq Ln");
        AllAddresses.Add(customer1Address);
        AllAddresses.Add(customer2Address);
        AllAddresses.Add(customer3Address);
        return AllAddresses;
    }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Customer(int id,string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        CustomerID = id; FirstName = firstName; LastName = lastName;
    }
    public static List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        var AllCustomers = new List<Customer>();
        var customer1 = new Customer(1, "James", "T");
        var customer2 = new Customer(2, "Donnie", "H");
        var customer3 = new Customer(3, "Sarah", "H");
        AllCustomers.Add(customer1);
        AllCustomers.Add(customer2);
        AllCustomers.Add(customer3);
        return AllCustomers;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Need more details. Whats the error you got?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message.The query is not returning any results. I'm binding it to a listview and I'm not getting any results. No error though. When I check it in debug mode after I assigned it as a datasource all the results for the inner key ect ect are null

Comment: post an answer to your question rather than editing the question, doing that makes this sites a useful resource for searching for existing solutions rather than just a place to ask questions. you will probably get a few upvotes in the course of time when people with similar problems find your answer

Comment: This isn't really an answer - it should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I know.. I dont have enough rep to vote it down though

Comment: @James: In the question you say you *do* get results, but all with the same address. That's the situation I've added an answer for. That's very different to not getting any results. Which is it?

Comment: @Jon Yes, you did fix that part, but I was hoping you could tell me how to fix it so that I will get results correctly - something is screwed up with how I'm joining, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning the first customer address because you've told it to:

```
AddressLine = addresses.Select(b => b.AddressLine1).FirstOrDefault()
```

Here, `addresses` is *all* addresses. I suspect you just want:

```
AddressLine = a.Select(b => b.AddressLine1).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Gave that a try, but it is only returning CustomerName - my List binds and leaves a blank space where the address should be.

Comment: @James: Look at what SQL is being generated, and run it in SQL Studio. See whether that gives you any results.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that? It's not querying from a dbml or context. I have 3 lists of objects and I'm trying to join them with linq just as an exercise

Comment: Off - the subject... You're book has pretty awesome reviews. Probably going to buy that sucka soon.

Comment: @James: Hope you like it :) I didn't realise this was LINQ to Objects.  That should make life easier. Could you post some test data then? I suggest you write a short but complete console app which you can post in its totality - that will get all the ASP.NET out of the equation, and mean we can concentrate just on the LINQ.

Comment: I put it all under Program.cs

Comment: @James: Cracking. I'll look now.

Comment: @James: Changing `addresses.Select` to `a.Select` as per my answer, your console app gives me the right results.

Comment: So I'm probably doing something dumb with my asp.net

Comment: that is so weird. Why does it work on the console, but not in my web form. I've double checked the webforms code and it all looks solid.

Comment: Just bought your book. Looks like it has some good stuff on linq which is what I need to learn.

Comment: @James: I don't know about that part... I'm not an ASP person, I'm afraid :( Possibly materialize the query results with a call to `ToList` at the end?

Comment: I figured it out - thanks for the help with the linq. got my references mixed up in the query on my original

Answer (score 5):

The query isn't very expressive.  If I was going to join three lists using LinqToObjects, I'd do this:

```
var query =
  from c in customers
  join xr in addressRelations on c.CustomerId equals xr.CustomerId
  join a in addresses on xr.AddressId equals a.AddressId
  select new {Customer = c, Address = a};
```

---

Looks like another mistake.  I bet that AddressRelId is the key to the AddressRelation table, and not what you want use to connect to the Address table.

```
.GroupJoin(addresses, 
ar => ar.Address**Rel**ID, 
a => a.AddressID,
```

---

In response to comment:

```
var query = customers
  .Join(addressRelations,
    c => c.CustomerId,
    xr => xr.CustomerId,
    (c, xr) => new {c, xr})
  .Join(addresses,
    x => x.xr.AddressId,
    a => a.AddressId,
    (x, a) => new {c = x.c, xr = x.xr, a = a})
  .Select(x => new {Customer = x.c, Address = x.a});
```

Comment: I like how short that syntax is in your first code snippet. How can I convert that to linq to objects syntax?. That's what I did the first time and it worked, but things got pretty sloppy when i tried to use linq to object syntax.